# Kohana image upload validation

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I'm having problems with image validation, documentation as always doesn't help, so there is my simple validation to check if image was uploaded

```
    $validate = Validation::factory($_FILES)
                ->rule('file', array('Upload::not_empty'));
```

But this gives me error 
`ErrorException [ Warning ]: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members`

What could be causing this error?

Comment: The information you need for validation of images is here: [Kohana Image Upload Example](http://cyberapp.ru/2012/08/05/kohana-file-upload-part-1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd argument for `rule` is a PHP callback. So this would suffice because the not_empty method in the upload class is static:

```
rule('file', 'Upload::not_empty');
```

You only really need to do the array syntax when the method is not static:

```
rule('file', array($class, 'method'));
```